# Importing classes causes Error: Uncaught syntaxerror unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, module

I try to import my Java Class yellow.js into my index.js and get

> "Uncaught syntaxerror unexpected identifier"

after some googeling I get suggestet to change my

```html
<script src="src/index.js"></script>
```

into

```html
<script type="module" src="src/index.js"></script>
```

but this leads to:

> Access to script at 'file:///D:/Game/src/index.js' from origin 'null'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only
>   supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension,
>   https

My Code looks like this right now:

index.html

```html
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <style>
            #gameScreen {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="gameScreen" width='600' height='600'></canvas>
        <script type="module" src="src/index.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

index.js

```js
    import Yellow from "/src/yellow";

    let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


    let yellow = new Yellow();
    yellow.draw();
```

yellow.js

```js
    export default class yellow{
      draw(ctx) {
            ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0';
            ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 50);
        }
    }
```

Did I miss something?

I didn't really understand where an how to add the `"type="module"` thing.

Comment: This lead to this Error: Access to script at 'file:///D:/Game/src/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On browsers, module names must have their extensions (so `yellow.js`, not `yellow`) unless they're listed in a [module map](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-map) for your page; relative module references must start with `./` or `../` (to distinguish them from references to modules listed in a module map).

So if you're not using a module map, this

```
import Yellow from "/src/yellow";
```

needs to be

```
import Yellow from "./yellow.js";
```

It's `./` because `index.js` and `yellow.js` are in the same place, and the relative path is relative to the module doing the import (`index.js`), not the HTML that imported that module.

---

Re the error you get when you do use `type="module"` (which you must do):

> This lead to this Error:
>
> > Access to script at 'file:///D:/Game/src/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Most browsers won't let you do this from a `file://` URL, although Firefox does. Even when using Firefox, though, it's best to use a local webserver for web development, as **many** things are either blocked or behave differently from `file://` URLs vs `http://` and `https://` URLs. Your IDE may have one embedded in it, or it's fairly straightforward to install Apache or nginx locally, or you might roll your own with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) and [Express](http://expressjs.com) or [Koa](https://koajs.com).

Comment: Thanks for the answear. But it leads to the same error as if i used the 'type='module'' thing.

Comment: @RedDeadRabbit - You have to use `type="module"`, and you can't do this from file system URLs.

Comment: So do i get this right, that i can't develop it on a local machine? i need to set up a server?

Comment: @RedDeadRabbit - Yes, you can develop on a local machine. Yes, you need a web server process. (Most IDEs can provide one for you, or installing one is fairly easy these days, or you can roll your own using Node.js and Express or Koa...)

Comment: @RedDeadRabbit - Actually, Firefox lets you load modules from a `file://` URL (provided the page is on a `file://` URL). Chrome doesn't. I strongly recommend using a web server process, though, for the reasons listed in the question.

Comment: I solved it with installing node.js and run and http-server in node.js command prompt. Works great. Thx for the support!