# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier is unexpected error

Tags: javascript

when importing class to another javascript file i catched an error called Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '

```
/*paddle.js*/
export  default class paddle
{
    constructor(gameWidth,gameHeight)
    {
        this.width=150;
        this.height=30;
        this.postion={
            x:gameWidth/2-this.width/2,
            y:gameHeight-this.height-10,
        }

    }
    draw(ctx)
    {
        ctx.fillRect(this.postion.x,this.postion.y,this.width,this.height);

    }
```

```
/*index.js*/
    import paddle from'/src/paddle';
    let canvas=document.getElementById('gameScreen');
    let ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    const GAME_WIDTH=800;
    const GAME_HEIGHT=600;
    let  paddle =new paddle(GAME_WIDTH,GAME_HEIGHT);
    paddle.draw(ctx);


}
```

i expect to see a canvas object (paddle)

Comment: Something is wrong with your braces. Not sure whether they look like that in your actual files as well?

Comment: Doesn't the error message say *which* identifier is unexpected? And from what line does it come?

Comment: index.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  ...this is the  excatly error that i catched

Comment: Does the environment where you try to evaluate this support module syntax?

Comment: There are many, many questions with this error in the title. Have you looked at any of them? For instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56826377/215552), which I found in the Related section to the right, seems to be very close to yours... and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56978416/215552), which even has the same exact class as yours. Perhaps you should ask your teacher? ;)

Comment: i tried the first one and i get  new error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'paddle' has already been declared"  although i declared it one  in index.js  and the second one didnt work